# Does JOSSO 1.8.10 support SAML 2.0?

Tags: spring, metadata, saml, josso

Does josso 1.8.10 support saml 2.0 ?
If so, how can i configured to work with saml 2.0 ?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does support SAML 2.0. Nowadays when you read 'SAML' somewhere almost SAML 2.0 is meant.

http://docs.atricore.com/josso2/2.4.0/josso-reference-guide/html/en-US/JOSSO_Reference.html#Identity_Provider_Setup

http://docs.atricore.com/josso2/2.4.0/josso-reference-guide/html/en-US/JOSSO_Reference.html#Service_Provider_Setup

Comment: Thanks but your answer related to JOSSO v.2 and my question is related to JOSSO v.1